# Suggestions on sendbird chat with angular 8

Tags: chat, angular8, pubnub, sendbird

I am having difficulty finding a solution for adding one to one for either pubnub chat or sendbird chat with angular 8. Ideally, it would be in a messages component and have a left side with all the members the user is chatting with and then a chat area. Can anyone share a resource ( not just sendbird/pubnub chat javascript SDK ). Anyone have a mock component.html and component.ts? Something that I can see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/tutorials/react - but this is built in React.

It has a live sample app with UI that shows you the channels you belong to on the left and you can click the 'people' icon on the top right to see who all is online in a particular channel. There is full source code available on Github as well for you to deploy as-is or customize as per your needs.

This (somewhat older, but still pertinent) series of blog posts specific to building a Chat app with AngularJS should help you - https://www.pubnub.com/blog/angularjs-chat-getting-started/ - it contains a fully working Angular app demo as well.

Beyond this, let me know what functionality are you looking for and I am happy to point you to a place that describes how to accomplish that.

Comment: Yeah but that tutorial is for react I'm using angular 8, I know they are both javascript based but functionality is different

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to AngularJS Chat app

Comment: Angular 8 and angular js are significantly different, so I don't think that tutorial would apply either.

Answer (score 0):

For angular 8, use node js to handle all pubnub configurations and route angular request to pubnub through node js. That's what I did with my angular 8 project

Comment: It is better to provide a sample code to demonstrate how you have done.